# Firefox extension : gMultiprocessBrowser is not defined

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am porting a Firefox v22 extention Firefox v31, my plugin works fine on FFv22 but its not working on FFv31.

In my plugin I have changed the overall browser look, so I have made changes in browser.xul.

The problem which i am facing is that I cannot open any webpage i.e none of the urls are redirected and when I am trying to use javascript call:

`gBrowser.selectedTab = gBrowser.addTab("");
gBrowser.selectedTab = loadURI(someURL,null,null);`

I am getting **ReferenceError: gMultiprocessBrowser is not defined**

exception.fileName gives me **chrome://browser/content/tabbrowser.xml**

linenumber: **1422**

I am also not able to add new tabs.

Comment: Without code, this question is off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working the way I want?**") must include: A) the desired behavior; B) a specific problem or error *and* C) **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** all ***in the question itself***. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Hi, as i have mentioned in my code i am getting an error ReferenceError: gMultiprocessBrowser is not defined on the code line gBrowser.selectedTab = gBrowser.addTab(""); , So did you really read the question or just randomly flagged it

Comment: I read it in its entirety. Looked to see if there was enough code to be able to duplicate the error (and thus be able to work on solving it for you). There was clearly not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which would allow us to duplicate the problem. You have stated you made changes in *browser.xul*, but did not include such changes. You did not state if you had attempted to perform those lines without the changes you have made to *browser.xul* and if it worked, or not.

Comment: Basically, you have left it such that we have to do a *lot* of work to try to help you. We generally try to provide answers that are tested and working. If we are going to try to verify our solution works *for you* it is *MUCH* easier to do so if we have your code to start from rather than having to make it all up. To do so, we each have to first duplicate the problem you are having then find a solution. Not having source code in the form of a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) makes helping you a *LOT* more work. Without such code there is less incentive to find an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, I was using old browser.js file & there has been a lot of changes in current version Firefox's browser.js so I just had to port my old code snippets into new browser.js file and it worked.